# Blazor OIDC Refresh Token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, blazor, openid-connect

I have a Blazor WASM app that uses OIDC authenication. I have the OIDC working.

```
            builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("offline_access");
                options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "Oauth URL";
                options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "client ID";
            });
```

I have the offline_access scope defined so that a refresh token is generated.

Once the user logins, the response from the token end point gets stored in session storage. This works great as long as the user doesn't exit the app. However, once the user closes the browser and then opens the browser again they have to log back into the site, even it the refresh token has not expired.

How can an Blazor WASM app using OIDC make use of the refresh token?

Thank you,
Travis

Comment: I am running into this issue.  Did you ever come up with a solution or a way to get around this limitation?  I was trying to come up with a way to check local storage manually when authentication starts before Session is reviewed.  I've followed the links mentioned below by Soumen, but they aren't very clear on if there is another option out there.

Comment: @Airn5475  yes and no, I switched my middleware to use openid dict. It's still an oauth 2 server but I am hosting the server. If your looking for a solution where you're not hosting the oauth server then I cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is recommended practice to store the oidc token in either session or local storage as it opens your app up to security vulnerabilities.

I am tending to use the "Backend for Frontend" (BFF) pattern now for authentication with Blazor.  It is a lot more involved than simply storing a token in local / session storage.  However, it pushes the token management from the client to the server and I believe it is much more secure.

Following is a pretty good reference for the method.
https://damienbod.com/2021/03/08/securing-blazor-web-assembly-using-cookies/

I'm not saying it's easy, because it's not.  However, I think that it is preferable than storing the tokens in the client, which is just like leaving the front door key under the doormat of your house.

(Note I know I haven't answered your question re. the refresh token, but I think that you need to solve the secure storage of the token first before worrying about refreshing it)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case since you are storing the data in the session storage , the data is lost as soon as the browser is closed . The `sessionStorage` is scoped to the browser's tab If the user reloads the tab, the state persists. If the user closes the tab or the browser, the state is lost. If the user opens multiple browser tabs, each tab has its own independent version of the data.

The  `localStorage` if used in which case the if the user reloads the page or closes and re-opens the browser, the state persists.

The storage is however not configurable ànd is not supported as explained here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20574

Comment: the AddOidcAuthentication uses session storage, (as far as I can tell) you cannot configure it like you can the msal one.

Comment: This explains the rational....https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20574